# Is there a single word (or expression) used to describe a person who does their job only when their boss is watching?

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests, expressions, adjectives, business-language

[image: look busy]

> "*Quick the **boss is coming**, we need to **look busy***"

Is there a ***single word*** (*or* ***expression***) to describe a person who *only* does their job while someone (the boss/manager) is watching, but who does *everything* ***except*** work while unsupervised.

We thought "*shirker*" might be an option, but that is just a lazy person who avoids work when ever possible. We're searching for a word that describes someone who *deviously pretends* to be *super productive & efficient* in front of (the "*right*") people, but actually reverts to doing virtually nothing as soon as people aren't watching.

> Note: we hate micromanaging people or *being* micromanaged, but there are people who will sit on Facebook or Buzzfeed all day if not *constantly* supervised... what are they called...?

*Thanks in advance*!

Comment: I had the perfect word in mind, but then my boss came into my cube and I had to quickly close EL&U and bring up another window.  Now I can't remember it.

Comment: In Italian we have "far finta di lavorare" which translated literally means a person who "fakes working". In English, I can only think of a person who "pretends to work when their boss is around". What about a *shadow worker*, derived from [*shadowbox*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/shadowbox)? Otherwise, a person who pretends to look busy but doesn't actually do any real work is still a shirker, loafer, a lazy worker, a substandard employee etc. How about **shammer**?

Comment: @HotLicks _love_ it! :-)

Comment: "*Trying to look busy is a hard work.*"

Comment: Boondoggle? Is the closest I could dig.

Answer (score 5):

"Slacker" has the sense of someone who doesn't do work until compelled to (e.g. By the boss's presence).  Where a "shirker" would like to avoid the work entirely, a slacker is perfectly capable of doing something but chooses not to at the moment.  Here's one of the definitions from Urban Dictionary:  "someone who is very lazy, doesn't do their work until the last minute, and frankly, enjoys it."  This doesn't catch exactly what you want, but I don't think you'll find something more specific to the boss coming into the room.

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour you are describing would be considered typical of a [disloyal employee](https://www.kirschenbaumesq.com/article/employment-issue-disloyal-employee) according to the following definition:

> - Most employers share a concern that employees may be disloyal.
> - *Disloyalty of course spans a wide spectrum,* ***from merely intentionally
>     failing to perform tasks***, accepting benefits personally that rightfully
>     belongs to the employer, to dishonesty and theft. Disloyalty can also
>     follow an employee who leaves the employer's employment taking with him as
>     much business as he can along with what the employer considers proprietary
>     and confidential information.

(www.kirschenbaumesq.com)

Answer (score 0):

**goof–off**:   "a person who avoids work or responsibility.."  http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/goof-off

It is more common to use goof off as a verb "Jim goofs off and we have to do his work."  The source cited above says that the first recorded usage was in 1953.